# Check if debian server has available unmounted hard drives

Tags: debian, hard-drive

hey I'm just wondering how I can check to see if my server has any available hard drives that havn't been mounted yet. I'm on debiab squeeze.

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The naive way is to compare `/proc/mounts` with `/proc/partitions`; assuming you've got no higher-level block devices (LVM, md), that should work well enough.

Answer (score 3):

lot of solutions for this. id prolly go with `fdisk -l` as a first port of call

Answer (score 2):

- `ls /sys/block`
- `blkid -c /dev/null`

Answer (score 0):

```
fdisk -l
```

Best place to look imo.

You can also reload the list of SCSI devices attached to the machine if you hot-swap a drive in using:

```
echo "- - -" > /sys/class/scsi_host/host#/scan
```

Where # is replaced by the device number.

This should then allow you to see it with

```
fdisk -l
```